# Overriding global htpasswd password protection

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, password-protection, .htpasswd

I am testing a Drupal site on a development server that runs bunch of other development sites. All of the sites are password protected globally by htpasswd. However, I need to not have password protection on my testing site because I am testing another authentication method using Apache directive "AuthType Shibboleth" in my .htaccess, which seems in conflict with Apache password.

How do I turn off htpasswd protection for my site only with global htpasswd in effect for other sites?

Answer (score 0):

The following line in an .htaccess in the root of the site you DON'T want protected always works for me:

```
satisfy any
```